# Floating toolbar for text selection Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How can I customize a menu for selected text to a TextField in Jetpack Compose? I mean something like this:

[image: Example]

Didn't find anything in the official documentation or on the Internet about how to do this using Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can provide a custom `TextToolbar` in the `LocalTextToolbar`. There, in the `showMenu` method, you must `startActionMode` as you would have done in the old Android.
`CustomTextToolbar`:

```
override fun showMenu(
    rect: Rect,

    onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
    onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
    onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
    onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)?

// Before 1.2.0 ActionCallback has to be defined like this:
// typealias ActionCallback = () -> Unit
//
//  onCopyRequested: ActionCallback?,
//  onPasteRequested: ActionCallback?,
//  onCutRequested: ActionCallback?,
//  onSelectAllRequested: ActionCallback?
) {
    println("showMenu")
    view.startActionMode(TextActionModeCallback())
}

class TextActionModeCallback(
) : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        println("onActionItemClicked $mode $item")
        return true
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        println("onActionItemClicked $mode $menu")
        return false
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        println("onActionItemClicked $mode $menu")
        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        println("onActionItemClicked $mode")
    }
}
```

As a ref how to implement it, check out compose source code: [AndroidTextToolbar](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/3167373c96f8ab86f2d102b0e520cf185cf52b46/compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidTextToolbar.android.kt#L32) and [TextActionModeCallback](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/3167373c96f8ab86f2d102b0e520cf185cf52b46/compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/actionmodecallback/TextActionModeCallback.android.kt#L30)

Then you can use it like this:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTextToolbar provides CustomTextToolbar(LocalView.current)
) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
}
```

To make this work for the entire application, you need to do it at the top of the composables tree, for example in `setContent`.

p.s. I had to define `ActionCallback`, because it's internal in compose. I believe it's a bug, so I've created [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197950089). It was [fixed](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha05) in Compose **1.2.0-alpha05**.

Comment: The linked issue has been fixed with v1.2.0-alpha05
 https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha05

Comment: I put all this in the code and when I long press on a text, hoping to get the popup menu, I do see prints of onActionItemClicked.  How can I get the usual menu up?

Comment: @LeoXJ As a ref how to implement it, check out compose source code: [AndroidTextToolbar](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/3167373c96f8ab86f2d102b0e520cf185cf52b46/compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidTextToolbar.android.kt#L32) and [TextActionModeCallback](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/3167373c96f8ab86f2d102b0e520cf185cf52b46/compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/actionmodecallback/TextActionModeCallback.android.kt#L30)

Comment: That's almost a start from scratch?

Comment: This kinda works, but if you have a keyboard connect this won't prevent from copy pasting. I haven't found a way to do it. :(.

Comment: @PedroVarela you can try ignoring `onValueChange` if diff is more than a single symbol - but it'll also will block keyboard suggestions from working

Comment: @PhilDukhov if you connect a physical keyboard to your phone, or even running the emulator, a want to prevent the text in the input field from being copied, I think this is more a task of the clipboard manager, but I haven't read that.