# How to remove copy, paste, cut ,call options of TextField which comes after selecting text of textfield in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have to hide copy, paste, cut ,call options of TextField which comes after long pressing text of textfield in jetpack compose. I am able to do this using below code of kotlin. I have to achieve this using TextField of Jetpack compose

```
LayoutBinding?.EtJioNumber?.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(object:ActionMode.Callback {

      override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        Console.debug(javaClass.simpleName,"onCreateActionMode")

        if (menu != null) {
          menu?.removeItem(android.R.id.shareText)
          menu?.removeItem(android.R.id.copy)
          menu?.removeItem(android.R.id.paste)
          menu?.removeItem(android.R.id.cut)
          menu?.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll)
          menu.removeItem(android.R.id.autofill);
        }


        return false
      }

      override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        Console.debug(javaClass.simpleName,"onPrepareActionMode")
      
       return false
      }

      override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        Console.debug(javaClass.simpleName,"onActionItemClicked")
        return false
      }

      override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        Console.debug(javaClass.simpleName,"onDestroyActionMode")
      }

    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floating toolbar for text selection Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956792/floating-toolbar-for-text-selection-jetpack-compose)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.