# Prevent cut/copy/paste in Textfield in Compose

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

---

Is there any way to prevent cut, copy, paste in TextField in Android Jetpack Compose?
I tried Modifier's pointerInput but it is not working.

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onLongPress = {
                Toast.makeText(context, "long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
        }
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Compose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floating toolbar for text selection Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956792/floating-toolbar-for-text-selection-jetpack-compose)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable copy/paste/cut in a TextField Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518908/how-to-disable-copy-paste-cut-in-a-textfield-jetpack-compose)