# How to disable copy/paste/cut in a TextField Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to find a simple solution on how to disable copy/paste/cut in a TextField. I did come across a couple of question but no answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an empty toolbar:

```
object EmptyTextToolbar: TextToolbar {
    override val status: TextToolbarStatus = TextToolbarStatus.Hidden

    override fun hide() {  }

    override fun showMenu(
        rect: Rect,
        onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Then you can provide it using `LocalTextToolbar`.

Most probably you also don't need text selection in this case, here's how you can disable it too:

```
var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTextToolbar provides EmptyTextToolbar
) {
    TextField(
        value = textValue,
        onValueChange = { newValue ->
            textValue = if (newValue.selection.length > 0) {
                newValue.copy(selection = textValue.selection)
            } else {
                newValue
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Bit overcomplicated isn't it?

Comment: after keeping this code,still i am able to select text and from the keyboard backspace able to remove the text

Comment: @MohdQasim you shouldn't be able to select multiple characters if you use my code from `onValueChange`. But this code doesn't expect to block backspace, so you still can remove characters one by one

Answer (score 2):

For now, you could just add a dummy Transparent Composable on TOP of the `TextField` and hook up it's click listener with the TextField's `focusRequestor`.

```
val tffr = remember { FocusRequestor() } // TextField Focus-Requestor

Box{

 TextField(
   value = value,
   onValueChange = { value = it }
   modifier = Modifier.focusRequestor(tffr).focusable()
 )

 Surface(
  modifier = Modifier.clickable { tffr.requestFocus() }.alpha(0)
 )

}
```

This way, when users try to click on the `TextField`, the tap would be intercepted by our dummy Composable, which would transfer the focus, effectively, to the TextField.

This means that they will technically be allowed to tap on the `TextField` and type in it, but the long press won't be registered by the field for them.

You could even add a Long-Click-Listener to the Surface using the `combinedClick` modifier, and display a toast to they users stating that the copy/paste actions are disabled, if that is something you'd require, that is.

Comment: A possible solution, but it also blocks clicks, which may be useful for moving the pointer

Comment: Makes sense Philip. Not a biggie for small value-holders though...

Answer (score -3):

Try this answer it's disable cut, copy in textfield

```
etSearchData.customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        }

    }
```

where etSearchData is your textField ID