# Jetpack compose number input field, prevent paste text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have input field defined like this:

```
BasicTextField(
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType=KeyboardType.Number),
                value = text,
                enabled = enabled,
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = Theme.typography.Body16,
                onValueChange = { onTextChange(it) },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        hasFocus = it.hasFocus
                    }
            )
```

which allows to enter just numbers and display numeric keyboard. But users can paste any text. How to prevent pasting text ? or completely disable paste option ?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518908/how-to-disable-copy-paste-cut-in-a-textfield-jetpack-compose

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the new value is digits only

```
 onValueChange = {
                if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(it))
                    onTextChange(it)
            }
```