# How to prevent copy/paste/cut context menu when right click on textfield [Jetpack Compose desktop]?

Tags: textfield, compose-desktop

[Reference solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518908/how-to-disable-copy-paste-cut-in-a-textfield-jetpack-compose)

i'm developing a compose desktop application.how to do same thing in this platform.i mean prevent copy/paste/cut context menu when right click on desktop.

i try to provide EmptyTextToolbar to LocalTextToolbar.it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emm,i find a solution

when compose popup context menu,they get menu item from LocalTextContextMenu.
so,i try to provides EmptyContextMenu to LocalTextContextMenu.it's working!

EmptyContextMenu:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
object EmptyContextMenu: TextContextMenu {
    @Composable
    override fun Area(textManager: TextContextMenu.TextManager, state: ContextMenuState, content:@Composable () -> Unit) {
        ContextMenuArea({
            emptyList()
        }, state, content = content)
    }
}
```

display code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication
    ) {
        var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalTextContextMenu provides EmptyContextMenu
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = textValue,
                onValueChange = { newValue ->
                    textValue = if (newValue.selection.length > 0) {
                        newValue.copy(selection = textValue.selection)
                    } else {
                        newValue
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

there is some reference link

[TextContextMenu interface define](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-core/blob/eb888df246ad3908183a21a5c1a938f46be246b8/compose/foundation/foundation/src/desktopMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/ContextMenu.desktop.kt#L144),

[interface default version](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-core/blob/eb888df246ad3908183a21a5c1a938f46be246b8/compose/foundation/foundation/src/desktopMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/ContextMenu.desktop.kt#L198),

[interface usage](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-core/blob/eb888df246ad3908183a21a5c1a938f46be246b8/compose/foundation/foundation/src/desktopMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/ContextMenu.desktop.kt#L69)