# Disabling paste for TextField in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to Disabling paste option for TextField in android jetpack compose. Is there any inbuilt method for textfield in android jetpack compose. Is there any way block copy/paste. Please help me to find the solution. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable copy/paste/cut in a TextField Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518908/how-to-disable-copy-paste-cut-in-a-textfield-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is any official way to prevent paste to TextField.
But you can use this trick.
Because usually the user pastes a text with more than one character and the paste of one character is not important.
When the difference between the new value of the field and its previous value is more than one or a few characters, it can be assumed that this was the result of the paste operation.

In each change of the text field, compare the new value with the previous value and if the difference is more than one character (or a few characters), do not accept the change.

```
@Composable
fun screen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier) {
        var txt by rememberSaveable {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }
        TextField(
            value = txt,
            onValueChange = {
                if (areStringsSimilar(str1 = txt, str2 = it, maxDifferences = 1)) 
                      txt = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Instead of being too precise, you can give more freedom to the user and allow changing a few characters at the same time.