Restrict copy of value from the OutlinedTextField from compose
I have a password field, OutlinedTextField; I want to restrict the user from copying/pasting (or both) values they provided in the field. My code is below. Kindly let me know how to approach this
val passwordFieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .semantics {
                contentDescription = context.getString(R.string.password_login)
            },
        value = passwordFieldValue.value,
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.text_field_grey),
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            fontFamily = robotoFont,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal
        ),
        enabled = !isInternetError.value && !isSyncError.value && !loginViewModel.loginState.value.isLoading,
        singleLine = true,
        onValueChange = {
            loginViewModel.loginState.value.hasError = false
            isLoginError.value = false
            passwordFieldValue.value = it
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            if(userNameFieldValue.value.isNotEmpty() && passwordFieldValue.value.isNotEmpty() && !isInternetError.value && !isSyncError.value) {
                userTapAction(
                    Pair(userNameFieldValue.value, passwordFieldValue.value),
                    context.getString(R.string.login_btn_action)
                )
            }
        }),
        label = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.password)) }
       
        })


Please only restrict copying, not pasting. Restricting pasting is a huge annoyance and doesn't improve security in the slightest.

The BasicSecureTextField from (I think) Compose 1.7.0-alpha05 onwards has this built-in.

Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72048150/11512499

@Leviathan I am using lower version of compose , by increasing the version I have major break so this won't be possible way, Thank for the suggestion, if any kindly let me know

Currently there is not a official, proper way to implement this. Have to wait for future updates
