# Jetpack Compose - SelectionContainer - how to add missing functionality?

Tags: android-view, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to replicate some View-based selected text behavior with Jetpack Compose. In both of these cases, I've long-tapped on the middle of the URL.

**View based:**

```
<TextView ... android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

[image: view-based-screenshot]

**Compose:**

```
    SelectionContainer {
        Text(...)
    }
```

[image: compose-based-screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshots, there are a few missing options in the **Compose** layout. *Is there a way to add this?* Yes, I know I can use `AndroidView` but is there a more composey way to do it? Here's what's in the **View** layout, but lacking from the **Compose** layout:

- "Share"
- "Select All"
- "Open" when a url is selected
- (AI-based?) auto selection of URLs. Tap and hold anywhere on the URL automatically selects the URL part.

Edit: I'm not asking for a *custom* toolbar, I'm asking for the one Google provides in TextView.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floating toolbar for text selection Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956792/floating-toolbar-for-text-selection-jetpack-compose)

Comment: Guess that's not possible at the moment...there is a selection state that `SelectionContainer` uses internally that would allow to pre-select stuff manually.....but it's not exposed.

Comment: I think you should create https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476 a feature request on compose issue tracker, right now such customisation doesn't seems to be supported.

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe it's still not working!

Answer (score 1):

While this is still not supported, if you use a TextField instead of a Text you at least get the "Select all" option too.

```
@Composable
private fun SelectableTextField() {
    TextField(
        value = "This is a selectable text",
        onValueChange = {},
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        readOnly = true,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val localTextToolbar = LocalTextToolbar.current

  localTextToolbar.showMenu(
                    rect = Rect.Zero,
                    onCopyRequested = {},
                    onPasteRequested =  {},
                    onCutRequested = {},
                    onSelectAllRequested = {})
```