# How Can I create a item in the text selected menu in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, selectedtext

I am developing an App with kotlin and Jetpack Compose and I want to add an item to this menu: [image menu 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0KS3.png)

when I select a text, I would like to show in this menu an option from my app, is this possible?

thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` for this. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/09/15/book-excerpt-floating-action-mode.html

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956792/floating-toolbar-for-text-selection-jetpack-compose/68966424#68966424

Comment: @CommonsWare this should be included as an answer